# How to select the closest matching row of values from a table using c#?

Tags: sql, .net, algorithm

Suppose I have a table(3 rows x 4 columns).

[image: Database Table]

Consider a database table where the first three rows are inputs. If the fourth row is added as a input to the table, the algorithm should match the incoming "A" input with previous all "A" inputs in the table and find the nearest match and it should do the same for B, C and D also. And finally it should select the appropriate row which has a closest match with the input and it should be selected. In this case the first row has closest match with the incoming fourth row and hence it should be selected.

*P.S :* SQL can also be used to achieve this.

Comment: You need to define "closest" better. Are you looking for the sum of the differences between columns to be minimum?

Comment: Yes.For eg,the incoming input 79.66795 is subtracted from 79.68406,79.71091,79.72479 in the first column.In this,when subtracting 79.68406-79.66795 yields the minimum values,i.e.0.01611.Likewise we have to do it for second,third and fourth column.So,finally one row(in this case first row) will have the minimum values.So,it should be selected.

Answer (score 0):

Something on the line of:

```
select *, abs(A-newA) from table group by A 
  having  abs(A-newA)=min(abs(A-newA))
;
// etc..
```

where newA, ... are to be substituted (prepared statement with value binding) with the new entry coordinates

```
select * from table where (abs(A-newA)+abs(B-newB)+...)=
  (select min((abs(A-newA)+abs(B-newB)+...) from table)
;
```